# C++ 11. Указатель на указатель на указатель функции

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11

Привет всем. Есть код.

```
#include <iostream>


const double * f1(const double ar[], int n);
const double * f2(const double [], int);
const double * f3(const double *, int);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    double av[3] = {1112.3, 1542.6, 2227.9};
    const double* (*p1)(const double *, int) = f1;
    auto p2 = f2;

    cout << "Using pointers to functions:\n";
    cout << "Address Value\n";
    cout << (*p1)(av, 3) << ": " << *(*p1)(av, 3) << endl;
    cout << p2(av, 3) << ": " << *p2(av, 3) << endl;
    const double* (*pa[3])(const double*, int) = {f1, f2, f3};
    auto pb = pa;

    return 0;
}

const double * f1(const double * ar, int n)
{
    return ar;
}
const double * f2(const double ar[], int n)
{
    return ar+1;
}
const double * f3(const double ar[], int n)
{
    return ar+2;
}
```

Вот эта часть кода "не работает". 
 `auto pb = pa;`

Выводит

> Compound array initializer is expected

Можете объяснить почему?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "не работает"? Ваш код собирается, а после указанного места никаких действий нет. Что не так-то?

Comment: [Работает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VHSgXGAoWIS84WbW), а если у вас он не работает, то следует привести текст ошибки и параметры сборки.

Comment: См. https://ideone.com/K2hhuh - как видите, компилируется...

Comment: Ах простите забыл там добавить при build-е выводит `Compound array initializer is expected`

Comment: @Abyx В выражении `auto pb = pa;` тип `pb` выводится в указатель на указатель на функцию. Писать `auto* pb = pa;` не надо. Тип `pb` выводился бы в массив при использовании `decltype(auto) pb = pa;`